# problem in converting NSString to NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to convert one `NSString` to `NSData`. on Using encoding am getting different value in `NSData` by displaying it using its description property.

I have

```
NSString *str=@"80369F4";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

on printing `[data description];` am getting some different values...

how to extract the same string from the `NSData`.. pl help me out on this problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear: is your problem NSData=>NSString or NSString=>NSData, or both?

Comment: @jv42-both conversions.....:: well answered by CharlieMezak & Micah Hainline..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSString's initWithData:encoding: method:

```
NSString *str=@"80369F4";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *sameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a new NSString:

```
NSString *newString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```